# Change font in converting svg to pdf in java

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, svg, batik

I have a java program for converting svg to pdf. In that svg file I have given Myriad Pro Light as the style, after converting to pdf the font is coming something else. Can anyone suggest me how to configure the font style programatically.

Comment: Can you give us more details on the software you're using for your conversion? If it allows font embedding it should expose mapping  facilities (font face -> font file).

Comment: I am not using any particular software to convert the svg to pdf, but I have converted the svgs  through java program.

Comment: you must be relying on a library or something; java does not have any built-in pdf nor svg facilities. Please explain how you are going from svg to pdf so somebody may help you.

Comment: okay I am using  apache batik library and lowagieto accomplish this task. Any other clarification or doubts please do approach me.

Answer (score 0):

Batik rely on AWT fonts for rendering SVG text.If the font is not found on the system or is not registered you'll end up with a default "sans serif" font.

You have to make sure the "Myriad pro light" font is installed on your system and that it has the exact same family name as the one referenced in your SVG file (look at the font-family attributes) ; correcting it in the SVG file if needed.

If installing the font system-wide is not an option, you can register it at runtime prior to  creating your SVGDocument instance using something like this

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("path_to_myriad.ttf"));
java.awt.Font font;
try {
    font = java.awt.Font.createFont(java.awt.Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
    ge.registerFont(font);
} catch (FontFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Sure...But You should help me do that. I dont know how to add long comments here. I even tried pasting the code I used for your reference but its not taking the long text. What to do?

Comment: Easiest way would be to paste in in a new pastebin I think ( http://pastebin.com/ )

Comment: We are restricted to use this site pastebin.com. So what can I do? Anyway can you tell me how you pasted the code in your comment